# AJAX PHP request after append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a drawing canvas where the drawing saves to the directory and a url saves to the database.

When the drawing is submitted, the canvas will dissapear and the drawing will load with its likes and comments.

So far, I have created a hidden form element which contains the url of the uploaded file as well as a new function which selects the image from the database, however I am receiving no alerts to ensure this works. When looking on the console, it says "200".

How would I go about making this possible?

```js
function doodleSave() {
 
 var canvas = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
 var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

 $.post('test.php', {data: canvasData}, function (response) {
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  
  if (data.filename !== false) {
   
   $('#doodle').slideToggle();
   $('#doodle-tools').fadeToggle();
   
      var content = '<input type="text" value="'+data.filename+'" id="doodle-load-value-holder"/>';
      
   $("#main-feed").prepend(content);
   
   var canvas = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas');
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   
   doodleLoad();

  } else {
   
   alert('unable to upload');
   
  }
 });
 
 
 
}


function doodleLoad() {
 
 var imagelocation = document.getElementById("doodle-load-value-holder");
 
 $.post('doodle-load.php', {data: imagelocation}, function (load) { 
  
  var data = JSON.parse(load);
  
  if (data.filename !== false) {
   
   
   alert('yes');
   

  } else {
   
   alert('unable to upload');
   
  }

  
  
 });
     
}
```

```html
<?php

$img = $_POST['data'];

require_once 'php/connect.php';
 
 try
 {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (image_url= :image_url)");
  $stmt->execute(array(":image_url",$img));
  $fileExist = $stmt->rowCount();
  if($fileExist != 0)
  {

   echo json_encode(['filename' => "true"]);
  }
  else
  {
   echo json_encode(['filename' => "not in database"]);
  }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
  $return_data = $e->getMessage();
 }
 exit();

?>
```

Comment: If you open your networks tab in the console, do both the AJAX requests start?

Comment: They do. I think I've found a solution to this. If I create a new php file and make the created div load that file the results will show?

Comment: Sure, you can start another AJAX request, ask for the content to PHP, return the content, and insert the content inside the div through the `.html()` method of jQuery. I don't know very well what's going on, but if you could group the two requests in order to start just one instead of both, it would be better. Actually you start the first one, get the results and start another one. Maybe you can group both in one